# Why can't I delete a file where I have group write permissions on?

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

I have a file with the following permissions:

`root:data`, and `chmod` set to 775.

My normal user, let's call him boby, is in the `data` group.

Why can't I delete the file with the user boby?

```
 rwxrwxr-x 18 root data 4096 2011-12-30 22:02 storage
 my user is in the group data but can't write into storage
```

Answer (score 38):

Because by deleting a file, you are not just modifying the file but also modifying its directory.

So if your file is:

```
rwxrwxr-x
```

You would be able to do:

```
cp /dev/null <filename>
```

But if your directory permissions are:

```
rwxr-xr-x  root  data  <directory name>
```

Then system will prevent you removing the file.

Comment: I have drwxrwxr-x on the directory, I think it has something to do with the d in front

Comment: @user56301 d just indicates that this file is a directory.  What's the ownership of the directory?

Comment: drwxrwxr-x 18 root data

Comment: Try running as user `boby` the following: `cd <directory> ; touch test_file ; rm test_file`

Comment: @user56301 can you create a file in that directory? if you can not, then you definitely can't delete a file there.

Comment: Permission denied, the user is in the group, the dir has write permission for the directory, but I can't create file. If I use 777 it works( as expected )

Comment: Isn't `/dev/null` read-only? How can you copy from it?

Comment: @Karlson About _"Because by deleting a file, you are not just modifying the file but also modifying its directory"_ - Does it only apply to the immediate parent directory, right?

Answer (score 16):

File deletion is based on directory perms, not file perms (*).

Do you have write permissions on the directory that contains the file?

(*) Caveat, you can have a directory where you enforce that only the owner of the file can delete it. This is useful for temp dirs.

Comment: Also have a look here: https://superuser.com/questions/784952/linux-group-member-cannot-delete-file-with-rw-permission where the same is discussed.

Comment: About _"Do you have write permissions on the directory that contains the file?"_  - Does it only apply to the immediate parent directory, right?

Comment: @ManuelJordan write permissions, yes. Think of a directory as a scratchpad that lists “these are all the files just under me”. To delete a file you kinda rewrite that scratchpad. But don’t need to rewrite anything above you. Other perms are important, i have some kid errands to finish but there’s some combination of missing R and X flags on parent dire that would make this difficult

Answer (score 1):

If the containing directory does not permit the user `boby` or the `data` group to write to it, then that would explain this behavior.

Comment: So the entire path needs group permission? It works like that.

Comment: @user: Not the entire path - just the file's immediate parent directory. You are only modifying the directory's contents. The *higher* parents *do not matter at all*.

Comment: I update the answers

Comment: This is not exactly true. You only need write perms on the containing directory. The perms can be any of user, group, or other, it doesn't have to be group perms that allow you.

Comment: @Rich: AFAIK, only one set is checked. If you are the owner, the system will only check 'owner' perms, not 'group' nor 'others'. If you are in the group, the system won't check 'others' perms. (`touch foo; chmod 6 foo; ls -l foo; cat foo`)

Comment: I have removed the "any parent of the containing directory" phrase from my answer. Not sure what I was thinking...

Comment: Psst!  The clue is in the final sentence of the question.  Hint: Your answer mentions permissions but omits another relevant factor.

Comment: @grawity true, sorry that I was unclear, the answer originally said "it checks groups" I just wanted to say "it may check users, groups, or other as appropriate", not that it will check all 3. But, you know I can't edit comments on stackexchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same thing, and ran into the same problem.

Starting a new terminal session the problem. This can be achieved by:

1. Logging out and logging back in
2. Going to one of the 6 ttys (Ctrl+Alt+F1-6) (Note: Ctrl+Alt+F7 is your GUI session)
3. using `su boby` to start a new session for user `boby`.

Cheers!

Comment: He mentions he is already logged in as boby

Comment: He needs to login again as `boby` - the old session seems to be stale and not reflect the group association changes.

Answer (score 1):

I bet the file you're trying to delete is in /tmp.

See [Linux - group member cannot delete file with rw permission](https://superuser.com/questions/784952/linux-group-member-cannot-delete-file-with-rw-permission)

/tmp usually has the "sticky" aka "restricted deletion" mode set (o+t). With this mode set, only the file's owner can move or delete files in that directory regardless of any permissions.

Answer (score -1):

the file you want to have delete permissions too, after a chmod 775 or 777,
place it under a directory which has been chmod 775 or 777 too.

e.g sudo touch /root/comments.db
sudo chmod 777 /root/comments.db
and then as a non sudoer : rm /root/comments.db # doesnt work

However, mkdir -p /root/comments/comments.db
sudo touch /root/comments/comments.db
sudo chmod 777 /root/comments/comments.db
sudo chmod 7775 /root/comments
and then as a non sudoer : rm /root/comments/comments.db # works