# Linux - group member cannot delete file with rw permission

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

Below shows a file, `/tmp/testfile`, owned by **user1** with group changed to **wheel** that also includes **user2**. The file has `rw` permission for the group. So shouldn't any member of the group be able to delete it? The example output below shows that **user2** is not able to delete the file. Why?

```
[user2@files ~]$ ls -l /tmp/testfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 wheel 0 Jul 18 18:54 /tmp/testfile
[user2@files ~]$ groups
user2 wheel
[user2@files ~]$  rm /tmp/testfile
rm: cannot remove `/tmp/testfile': Operation not permitted
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I delete a file where I have group write permissions on?](http://superuser.com/questions/373115/why-cant-i-delete-a-file-where-i-have-group-write-permissions-on)

Comment: Furthermore to the complete explanation by @grawity, a good solution is to create your 'own' directory under `tmp` and fix the sticky situation

Answer (score 35, accepted):

First, you're looking at the wrong permissions. When you move/rename/delete a file, you're only modifying the *parent directory* – the file's own permissions are not checked. You only remove an entry from the directory's list of files. Therefore you should check the permissions of the parent directory (in this case `/tmp`).

```
$ ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 15 root root 460 Jul 19 15:18 /tmp/
```

Second, `/tmp` is special. On practically all systems, it's writable by anyone (`ugo=rwx`), so at first glance, it looks like anyone could rename or delete any file in it. This would of course make it easy (well, even easier) to create problems for other users, therefore `/tmp` always has the "sticky" aka "restricted deletion" mode set (`o+t`). With this mode set, only the file's owner can move or delete files in that directory, regardless of any permissions.

(On GNU coreutils, the `chmod(1)` manual page has a section about the ["restricted deletion flag or sticky bit"](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html#RESTRICTED_DELETION%20FLAG%20OR%20STICKY%20BIT).)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue due to second point of special sticky permission. I tried to remove it `chmod o-t /tmp` and then re-tried to delete the file, but it is still complaining the same.

Comment: Not only the file owner can delete files under said directory, but also root and the owner of the directory (e.g. /tmp).

Comment: About `o+t` - `o` is for _others_, but What does `t` mean? - I always have read about r/w/x

Comment: `t` means "sticky". It says so in the post...

Comment: @user1686 About the "parent directory" - Does it only apply to the immediate parent directory, right?